# Python File object to Flask's FileStorage

Tags: python, testing, flask

I'm trying to test my upload() method in Flask. The only problem is that the **FileStorage** object in Flask has a method save() which the python **File** object does not have.

I create my file like this:

```
file = open('documents-test/test.pdf')
```

But I cannot test my upload() method because that method uses save().

Any ideas how to convert this File object to a Flask Filestorage object?

Comment: Hi. I don't understand what you are trying to do here. Do you mean test it without passing the file to flask?

Comment: My handle_upload method takes a file object as an argument. The problem is this file needs to be a FileStorage Object from Flask and not a File object from Python. This is no problem if I load the file on the webpage but I want to be able to test the method separately

Answer (score 32):

http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage

I needed to use the flask `FileStorage` object for a utility outside of the testing framework and the application itself, essentially replicating how uploading a file works using a form.  This worked for me.

```
from werkzeug.datastructures import FileStorage
file = None
with open('document-test/test.pdf', 'rb') as fp:
    file = FileStorage(fp)
file.save('document-test/test_new.pdf')
```

Comment: @neurosnap is there a way for us to deconstruct the file and reconstruct in celery?

Comment: @user805981 you could try to encode and decode the image in base64

Comment: @Alp are you sure this is the right way to do this? It doesn't feel right to send raw bytes to encode and decode...

Answer (score 4):

The `get` and `post` methods of the Flask test client invoke [`werkzeug.test.EnvironBuilder`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/test/#werkzeug.test.EnvironBuilder) under the hood - so if you pass in a dictionary as the keyword argument `data` with your file you should be able to work with it then:

```
def test_upload():
    with open("document-test/test.pdf", "rb") as your_file:
        self.app.post("/upload", data={"expected_file_key": your_file})
        # Your test here
```

Answer (score 2):

@neurosnap 's answer got me started but didn't quite work. The following did...

```
file_loc = open('./tests/sample data/2 Candidates.csv', 'rb')
file = werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage(file_loc)
file.save(dst='document-test/test_new.pdf')
file_loc.close()
```

Python throws an error if you don't close the file at the end.