# python flask: mimic werkzeug FileStorage object

Tags: python, werkzeug

I have the following route in a flask application which accepts an uploaded file and throws the file object into a function for validation. Here's a barebones example:

```
def is_file_valid(file):
    if file.filename == 'test':
        return True
    return False

@app.route('/validate', method=['POST'])
def validate():
    file = request.files['file']
    if is_file_valid(file):
        return redirect(url_for('somewhere'))
    return redirect(url_for('somewhere_else'))
```

I'm trying to create a unittest to test the `is_file_valid` function but I'm having trouble creating the `FileStorage` object flask uses which appears to be very similar to a standard python file object ([docs](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage)).

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
import io
with io.open('/path/to/file', 'rb') as f:
    print(f.filename)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'filename'
```

Any idea how I can mimic werkzeug's `FileStorage` object in a regular python script?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18249949/python-file-object-to-flasks-filestorage

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python File object to Flask's FileStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18249949/python-file-object-to-flasks-filestorage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18249949/python-file-object-to-flasks-filestorage). Just need to wrap the python file object in the werkzeug [FileStorage](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage) class.